# Token ivalid (Google Login api ) OAuth 2.0 - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-signin

Im on stuck. i dont know how to resolve this error:

```
 [invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: The ID Token contains invalid claims: {iat=date...}
```

this message does show me when i try login with google provider:

let me sho you some simle code

```
package com.silva.oauth2.social.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class securityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

```
spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
            client:
                registration:
                    google:
                        clientId: <client-id>
                        clientSecret: <client-secret>
```

i used

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

this dependency:

Im trying login with OAuth 2.0 Google api with spring boot

Answer (score 0):

The last part of your error message "The ID Token contains invalid claims: {iat=date...}" says iat, namely "**issued at**". There might be an issue with the claims in the ID Token. I would firstly check it and then compare with your system's date.